# Is there any computer specific information besides the IP address for tracking?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, tracking

I am developing a program to that only allows the same computer to view a specific page once, and after that I am blocking access to that page.

My question is, the IP address works ok but some users have a new IP every time they visit the site. I have come across other sites in the past that use some other means of tracking users, as even with a different IP on the same computer I can't view restricted content.

Anyone have any thoughts?

What are the other option(s) to the IP Address?

Comment: Logins and passwords tied to a resource it's hard enough to get a lot of.

Comment: You don't. Everything can be spoofed. Even if you use cookies (the obvious approach), local storage etc, cookies can be disabled and local storage deleted.

Comment: It depends what your wanting to achieve, using a login or even just an email address will tie the user to the restriction.

Comment: There's *many* unique factors to each browser; [Panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/) demonstrates a few of the lesser-known ways.

Comment: Logging in would be great, except that people can just create a second account and do access the same information again. That's why I'm looking for another approach.

Comment: @FredJLangemarkIII to put you into perspective, does Facebook prevent you from making a 2nd? 3rd? Nth account? Nope. The service cannot prevent that.

Comment: And some network setups present the _same_ IP address to the outside world from every one of the computers inside their network. Tying access to the IP address is a very bad idea. If you want to lock it up, do it properly and require username/password tied to a long-term email address.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267903/how-can-i-prevent-users-from-voting-more-than-once-in-1-hour (slightly different problem, but all the proposed solutions apply)

Comment: @paxdiablo even an email won't prevent a user from making another account, though it will impede the incomming "sign-up spam" by creating more effort for another email for another account.

Comment: @Joseph, no it won't prevent it. Nor will more security on your house keep out the determined robber. The idea is to deter a greater proportion of people from "bending" the rules. That was why I used the term "long-term email address" - disallow those that are known to be easily made like hotmail, gmail, etc. Even that won't stop someone who knows what they're doing but it may at least slow the great unwashed :-)

Comment: If you really want to restrict to people rather than account, send out those ever-changing password generators that the banks use along with a PIN (two-factor authent) - that'll work, though the cost may be beyond what you're willing to pay.

Comment: Blocking by IP may cause problems, as IP's are often recycled by ISPs, meaning someone who hasn't used your site could end up being blocked.

Comment: @paxdiablo i did say it won't prevent :)

Comment: You could use something like evercookie, but even then, if the user wants to delete all their local storage they will find a way.

Comment: @Joseph: "no it won't prevent it" => "I agree with you that it won't prevent it". Sorry, wasn't trying to argue, you're dead right about that point.

Answer (score 3):

The best you can do is tie up the functionality to a user account. That way, you have control over what the user sees.

Tying up to a machine isn't reliable.

- IPs change frequently or can be spoofed. What if the user used proxies?
- UAs can also be spoofed
- Cookies can be disabled or deleted
- LocalStorage can also be deleted and is not widely supported

Basically, a user has all the freedom to be free from your restrictions unless they opt to sign up with your service. That's what you call *privacy* as well.

And did you ever think when users share PCs? What if your dad got blocked on your laptop? You can't view it on your laptop anymore.

Comment: if he wants the user to have access only once, then the user would just make a new account. Using accounts is more a way to grant repeated access to some protected resource.

Comment: @databyss that you can't prevent since the server cannot see people. They just see accounts. That's the best one can do to control users.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one method that you can use to be unique to any one computer.

You can set a cookie on that browser, but the user could use another browser or just delete the cookie.

There are 3rd party services that run a flash module to get computer specific data to create a guid that you can use, but that's more expensive and also requires the user to load your flash module, which means it wouldn't work on some mobile browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If the page is not public and sent to the user (ie by email), you can generate the URL with an ID, and them invalidate the ID once that the page is visited.

This is the usual approach used by email validation pages.